# How can I best organise a Jekyll + Bootstrap + Git site?

Tags: bootstrap, code-layout

So after many many many years of building sites from scratch (and doing a lot of the lifting myself) I've dipped my toes into two projects that have been around for a few years that I've been avoiding: Bootstrap and Jekyll.

The design was a very customised job that required me to dig into the LESS so I've got the Bootstrap source files, source assets and a build directory within that directory. Then there's the Jekyll side. That has its own structure, I'm symlinking in the Bootstrap build directory, and the final content (the stuff I want to actually serve) buried in `_site` directory.

Here's how it looks:

```
/.git/*
/.gitignore
/bootstrap/
/bootstrap/... a load of source files ...
/bootstrap/bootstrap/  # the build output
/jek/
/jek/... all the jekyll files ...
/jek/bootstrap/  # symlink on ../bootstrap/bootstrap/
/jek/_site  # the stuff I actually want to upload - but don't really want in git
```

In *my* history, I've either been dealing with a Django project layout (which makes a fair amount of sense) or a static layout. What I have here is two separate build systems and it's driving me nuts.

Is there a better way of structuring all this junk, or failing that, is there a way I can make bootstrap output directly into the jek directory? How do you handle co-dependent static sites like this?

Comment: I guess this makes it easier to start off: http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html

Comment: Why is it driving you nuts?

Comment: If it's Jekyll, Bootstrap and GitHub, I'd make full use of this guy's vids:  https://www.youtube.com/user/KepowOb/

Answer (score 1):

- Separate build file from source.

  ```
  /jek/_site  # the stuff I actually want to upload - but don't really want in git
  ```

  you can put it off from your main branch, jekyll has [Continuous Integration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/) support. How to do it you can read the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/travis-ci/).

  > it will not be easy, it's like setup new project. And i assume you are not yet familiar with it
- Bring the bootstrap inside jekyll directory.

  ```
   /jek/bootstrap/  # actual boostrap source    
   /jek/bootstrap/dist/  # the build output
  ```

  read [default configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#default-configuration), it has

  - destination , in case prev options do not suite with you
  - include , include boostrap directory

    > Force inclusion of directories and/or files in the conversion.
  - keep_files , to keep `.less` if necessary.

The issue on jekyll to support less is in active and now [closed](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/63), So no official support yet. But you have alternative [Rake or Gulp](http://www.mikeniebling.com/Setting-Up-Jekyll-With-LESS/), [shell script](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/07/07/the-ideal-less-workflow-with-git/). When you use Continuous Integration like travis to push your generated file from jekyll, you can also compile less via [before_script](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/). With that i hope you have cleaner code-layout and single root folder, without _site directory.